# Using State Machine to implement a Poller system

Tags: java, spring, architecture, backend

I am trying to build an `http poller system` it is supposed to be doing the following:

For each user, Try to get a connection to the server, If it fails, check the failure reason, maybe that server is not available, so try out another one, if the reason is wrong credentials do something else..
As soon as we get connection established for that user, we start polling the server for some information on the user

And I was thinking of a `state machine`, where each user has an instance of the state machine (stored in a map userId -> statemachine) and I have some scheduled tasks, one that fetches data of all users each 1second lets say, it filters state machines where the current state is connected..

Would that be a good idea? Does it make sense to use a state machine for such a problem?

Comment: Personally i have worked on this state machine implementation by linked in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to implement it using a state machine. State Machine has three states, INITIAL, NEXT_STEP, and FINAL, and every state has an Implementation of the doSomething() method. which takes an argument and depending on the argument it can jump to the next state. if you want to customize you state machine check this opensource implementation by linkedin to implement a state machine which was a valid use case. you can chcek out the design here
[LinkedIn URL Shortner](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/06/open-sourcing-url-detector--a-java-) 
Model a State Machine using a Java Enum. 
And for scheduled task you can use

```
CompletableFuture
```

find more details here. [Completeable Future](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)